# "He likes writing poems" or "He likes to write poems"

Tags: gerunds, to-infinitive

I think both of the following are grammatically correct, aren't they?

> - He likes **writing** poems.
> - He likes **to write** poems.

<strike>but which form is more common in daily conversation use? *like + ing* or *like + to infinite* ?</strike>

**Update:**

Is there any different in meaning between them (*like + ing* and *like + to infinite*)? when can use each one of them?

Comment: It's really difficult for us to answer "which is more common" questions because it's not one set answer. They're both common, depending on the person/region/time of day (kidding)... I really think you'll be happier asking questions that aren't about "commonality".

Comment: @Catija Can I change it to: which form is more common in daily conversation use for native speaker of British English? Does this make it more specific?

Comment: Not really. You're still asking which is more common. It's like asking "Is it more common for Brits to eat bananas or oranges?" And the reality is, they're both extremely common, so which is more common is irrelevant. If 35 out of 100 people eat bananas but 30 out of 100 eat oranges, that's still a lot of people. We're not talking about "Bananas vs star fruit" where bananas is 35 and star fruit is 1.

Comment: @Shannak: I'm not sure how useful this might be, but my guess is that for *most* such "verb1 + verb2" combinations, the second one is more commonly expressed as an infinitive rather than a gerund/continuous participle. See [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=liked+to+have%2Cliked+having&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cliked%20to%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cliked%20having%3B%2Cc0) comparing ***liked to have/having***.

Comment: @Shannak: Again, I'm not sure exactly *what* you could learn from that information that would help you use English more naturally. Note that in your exact example both forms are very common, as pointed out. But if we consider *He **intends** to write poems*, for example, the fact of the matter is that you'd very rarely come across *He intends writing poems*. In the same general area, you should also note that *He **hopes** writing poems* isn't even a valid English construction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you again,  "When a verb is followed by another verb, the second verb must be either an infinitive with 'to' or an -ing form ...  The form of the second verb depends on the first verb, and/or the speaker's intended meaning." http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/flatmates/episode84/languagepoint.shtml     So, I Just want to understand what the speakers intend meaning when the use like + ing or when the use like + to

Comment: @Shannak: Even that BBC advice isn't strictly true. In your specific example, the form of the second verb doesn't depend on the fact of the first verb being ***to like***, but it doesn't depend on the speaker's intended meaning either (both forms are valid, and mean ***exactly*** the same). So that one's purely a ***stylistic choice***. On the other hand *I regret **to say** it's true* doesn't mean the same as *I regret **saying** it's true*. And *I like to box* can only mean I like *doing* the activity, but *I like boxing* could mean that OR it could mean I just like it as a non-participant.

Comment: There's some potentially useful stuff on this related ELU question: [When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinitive will express a general situation, a general truth:

**He likes *to write* poems**

Poetry is one of the things he likes to write.

The -ing form

**He likes *writing* poems**

draws attention to something *ongoing* about the act: he likes the *process* of writing a poem, the concentration of thought, the free association, whatever.

Or if he has just been hired by a greeting card company to write couplets about life events, we might use the -ing form to say that he likes his new job, where his *day-to-day* task is to write poems.

> Does Bob like his new job?
>   --Yes, he likes writing poems all day, every day.

It is not that we couldn't say "He likes to write poems all day,every day", it's just that the -ing form fits better in that it goes with the idea of the ongoing process or the day-to-day recurrence of the act.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but I'm not really convinced "ongoing activity" is a major factor influencing verb form here. To my mind, it's more that the continuous form is effectively a ***gerund noun***, which we're more likely to favour when it identifies a "known activity". And I think because of that the gerund probably works (slightly?) better in your ***writing poems all day*** example because both conversants already *know* that's what Bob does in his new job (i.e. - it's not exactly "new information").

Comment: I think you're stating it backwards. If you wanted to express the idea that he likes the process of writing poems, or likes his new job where he writes poems all day, every day, which form do you choose, **to write** or **writing**?

Comment: I suspect the main reason for favouring the gerund in your final example is  simply that there's a degree of parallelism between the two nouns, which are effectively being equated ***as nouns*** *(his new job = writing poems all day)*. But I don't think "extending" the process of *writing poems* by appending *all day, every day* has any real bearing on the issue - to me, it doesn't suggest anything significantly different to *...loves **to write poems** all day, every day*.